# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from

Tags: php, laravel

I hope I can help if possible, I can have a backend in Laravel and I need to consume some SOAP web services, for this I am using the native `SoapClient()` class. I'm getting this error:

> SOAP ERROR: Analysis scheme: you cannot import the scheme from http://[redacted]?xsd=xsd0

I cannot display the URL because it is a private but external server of the company. Here is my code:

```
public function getCotizacion(){

    // phpinfo();

    $Empresa = $this->set_Empresa();
    $Sistema = $this->set_Sistema();
    $Direcciones = $this->set_Direcciones();
    $namespace = "http://[redacted]";
    $IdConfiguracion = $this->set_IdConfiguracion();
    $Solicitante = $this->set_Solicitante();
    $FechaRegistro = date("c");
    $WCFBroker = $this->set_WCFBroker();

    $options = array(
        "trace" => 1,
        "encoding" => "UTF-8",
        "verifypeer" => false, 
        "verifyhost" => false,
        "proxy_port" => 7801, 
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2, 
        "trace" => 1, 
        "exceptions" => true, 
        "cache_wsdl"=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE

    );

    // SOAP client
    $soapClient = new \SoapClient($WCFBroker, $options);

    $auth = array(
        'Empresa' => (string) $Empresa,
        'Sistema' => (string) $Sistema,
        'Direcciones' => (string) $Direcciones
    );

    $header = new \SoapHeader($namespace, 'SeguridadHeaderElement', $auth, false);
    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    // nodos de arreglo body
    $request0 = new stdClass();
    $request0->FechaHora = $FechaRegistro;

    $request1 = new stdClass();
    $request1->ConsecutivoConfiguracion = $IdConfiguracion;
    $request1->Solicitante = $Solicitante;
    $request1->Parametros = new \SoapVar($Trama, XSD_ANYXML);

    $parameters = new stdClass();
    $parameters->InfoSolicitud = array('InfoTransaccion' => $request0, 'Cotizacion' => $request1);

    $Info = array();
    try {
        $Info['Info'] = $soapClient->CotizarPoliza($parameters);
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        $Info['Info'] = $fault;
    }

    $Info['request']['headers'] = $soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders();
    $Info['request']['body'] = $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
    $Info['response']['headers'] = $soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders();
    $Info['response']['body'] = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();

    return $Info;

}
```

The error paints this line as the one that is failing:

```
$soapClient = new \SoapClient($WCFBroker, $options);
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: You did display the url in the title. Maybe you'd like to delete from there as well.

Comment: Thanks!, could you help me?

Comment: I cannot.. sorry